# how to detect click outside of push menu and close menu

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript to open a push menu.But, I'd like to add the feature that if the mouse clicks outside of the push menu, it will close the menu.  I've never coded this before so really unsure of where to begin.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $menuLeft = $('.pushmenu-left');
  $nav_list = $('#nav_list');
  $nav_list.click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('.pushmenu-push').toggleClass('pushmenu-push-toright');
    $menuLeft.toggleClass('pushmenu-open');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="pushmenu pushmenu-left">
  <div class="pushmenu_inner">
    <ul class="links">

      <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Missions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Give</a></li>



    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: where is `nav_list` is present in your DOM?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. What did you try? Any research?

Answer (score 0):

Add event to trigger click operation and follow if it contains your menu or not.
I am giving an example, I hope it will help you with solving your issue.

html

```
<nav class="pushmenu pushmenu-left" id='menuBar'>
  <div class="pushmenu_inner">
   <ul class="links">
     <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Missions</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Give</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Javascript

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(e){   
   if (document.getElementById('menuBar').contains(e.target)){
       console.log('clicked inside');
       // toggle your menu according to your requirements
   } else{
       // toggle your menu according to your requirements
       console.log('clicked outside');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Jquery

`$(document).click(function () {
        //Write your code here 
    });`

it means when you are clicked outside that part your respective code will run

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I added an initial style to hide menu. You can then display the menu using the menu button or clicking on the document.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu').click(function() {
        if($('nav').is(':visible')) { 
            hideMenu();
        }
        else {
            $('nav').show(function() {
                 $(this).animate({left:'0'});
                 $('#menu').html('hide menu');
            });
        }
    });

    $(document).click(function(e) {
        if(!$(e.target).closest('#menu').length && $('nav').is(':visible')) {
            hideMenu();
        }
    });
});

function hideMenu() {
    $('nav').animate({left:'-100px'}, function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $('#menu').html('show menu');
    }); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="menu">show menu</button>
<nav class="pushmenu pushmenu-left" style="display:none; left:-100px; position: relative">
  <div class="pushmenu_inner">
    <ul class="links">
      <li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Missions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Give</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```